# Ghidra with Swift/Objective-C datatypes (NSString)

Tags: ghidra

I'm new to using Ghidra, so apologies if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer.

I'm looking at an iOS app, and I can see a function signature that looks like this:

```
ID Class::DoTheThing(ID param_1, SEL param_2, ID param_3)
```

I know that `param_3` is an `NSString`, but Ghidra doesn't seem to know what an `NSString` is.

Is there a datatype library that I can add to Ghidra to give it support for this, or do I need to manually tell it what an `NSString` looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed this guide on PoomSmart's GitHub page (https://github.com/PoomSmart/IDAObjcTypes) and it seems to have worked. PoomSmart is quite respected in the jailbreak community and I have used their tweaks for long with no issues.

There is one additional step not explicitly mentioned in the guide, which is to select the program architecture. Since I didn't specifically know what to pick, I tried a few of the ARM processor options and it looks good.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll check that out.